# How to specify VS svccutil to generate web service using Runtime.Serialization instead of XML.Serialization

Tags: wcf, serialization, binding, visual-studio-2019

Is there any way to specify the way i want the response to be deserialized? My class was auto generated using XML.Serialization and i think if i change the format i will be able to read the response from the web service. I'm currently getting a null response. and everything works fine in SOAP UI.

Comment: Do you mean that the automatically generated proxy class calls the service and gets an empty response?

Comment: No i meant instead of auto generating the proxy class using Xml.serialization can it be possible to tell to use runtime.serialization instead. I changed the wsdl manually and i was able to have a different format but i needed to know if there is another way.

Comment: I think you can use the channel factory to call the service, using the channel factory to call the service does not require the WSDL of the service.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong, in case it can help anyone else. It worked in SOAP UI but i had to validate the response there as well, it was working but there were new variables added so that's why I was getting a null response, since the response method needed to be updated to use the new variables.